# How does the attack / release element of this audio compressor function?

Tags: audio, current-source, current-mirror, current-sink, voltage-controlled-amplifier

This is an audio compressor circuit based on (and designed by the makers of) the [THAT 4301](http://www.thatcorp.com/4301_Analog_Engine_Dynamics_Processor.shtml). U2B converts the AC input to RMS, which is then inverted by U2D. When there is no signal input to the circuit (or when the signal is below the threshold), the output of U1A will be high, thus the current at the emitter of Q5 will charge up C18 until D6 becomes reverse biased. When signal is above the threshold, U1A will go low, and C18 will discharge via the Q3 current sink. The voltage on the capacitor is buffered by J113 and then used as a gain control by the 4301P.

What confuses me is how the circuit around C18 and Q2 stabilises.

- When the circuit is initialised there will be zero volts at the gate of Q2 and the positive side of C18. The voltage at the emitter of Q5 will also be zero as there is no resistance to convert the current to voltage. So how does D6 become forward biased in order to for Q5 to charge C18?
- Furthermore, if the gate of Q2 is zero volts then won't the gate-source voltage of Q2 be very positive? I can see that the source voltage will be slightly above -V due to R34 but not enough to make the gate-source voltage negative, as required for normal functionality?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Question 1:

Q4 and Q9 provide an adjustable bias to Q5 such that Q5 injects a constant current into D6 and D7 (don't forget they are PNP transistors so the relevant voltages are relative to V+).

At turn-on the voltage at the gate of Q2 will be zero (relative to V-). The voltage at the source will be a couple of volts higher depending upon the characteristics of Q2 (all JFETs are depletion mode devices).

This source voltage will be fed back to U1 inverting input and result in the U1 output being high since the non-inverting input being close to ground (assume VR7 wiper at the grounded end for initial analysis).

Since the U1 output and D7 voltage is high D7 will not be conducting - all the current from Q5 will pass through D6 and into C18 causing it to charge towards V+.

The source of Q2 will follow C18 until the voltage fed back to U1 inverting input will cause the output of U1 to drop turning D7 on and diverting current from D6. This will reach an equilibrium with the voltage at the source of Q2 at ground potential.

If the voltage from VR7 changes the voltage on C18 will follow with the restriction that the charging current can never exceed that from Q5.

Similar activity will occur with D8, D9 and Q3 if negative going changes.

Question 2: With Q2 gate at zero the current in Q2 will equal IDSS. R34 (5.1k) will have been selected such that IDSS can cause sufficient voltage to be developed across R34 to bias the gate negatively relative to the gate for equilibrium. This equilibrium will be maintained as the voltage across C18 changes.